# How to create a tagging system with NHibernate (many to many)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I'm learning NHibernate and hoping you guys could help me a bit about Tag Cloud design and solutions.

I have 3 tables which are "News", "Tags" and "News_Tags" with Many-To-Many relationship and the "News_Tags" is the link table.

Options:

1. **cascade="all", cascade="all-delete-orphan"** If I delete one of the news records, the it will delete all my news records which have the same tags.
2. **cascade="save-update"** It works with save and update, but if I try to delete news it will give the error: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)

Here is my mappings:

Tags:

```
<class name="Tag" table="Tags" lazy="false">
    <id name="TagID">
    <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="TagName" type="String"></property>
    <property name="DateCreated" type="DateTime"></property>

    <!--inverse="true" has been defined in the "News mapping"-->
    <set name="NewsList" table="New_Tags" lazy="false" cascade="all">
    <key column="TagID" />
    <many-to-many class="New" column="NewID" />
    </set>
</class>
```

News:

```
<class name="New" table="News" lazy="false">
<id name="NewID">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="Title" type="String"></property>
<property name="Description" type="String"></property>

<set name="TagsList" table="New_Tags" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="NewID" />
  <many-to-many class="Tag" column="TagID" />
</set>
</class>
```

Can anyone provide some solutions for this? 
[@Lck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003128/nhibernate-many-to-many-delete-all-my-data-in-the-table/2003189#2003189) mentioned I could do this manually, can anyone provide some code sample for me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer I gave a while ago:

[What is the correct way to define many-to-many relationships in NHibernate to allow deletes but avoiding duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695063/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-many-to-many-relationships-in-nhibernate-to-all/1697978#1697978)

It is not answering your quesiton directly but through its extreme solution and the comments it got you may understand what needs to be done to achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: I have spent 3 nights on this and almost give up. I put the inverse="true" into a wrong mapping file. Thank very much. Did you write any blogs or articles so I can follow them. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I do not have a blog at the moment but I am working on it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With `cascade="all"`, deleting a News object should simply delete all the corresponding rows in the New_Tags table, shouldn't it? I don't think it would delete all the News items that are tagged that way. Is this not the behaviour you want?